# how to move activity to background in android without pausing it?

Tags: android, android-activity, send, move

I want ask like in title. how to move/send activity to background in android without pause it?
for example in this method:

```
public void onBackPressed () {
    //here what i should wrote to back my previous activity and not stop or pause current
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible. By definition:

- `onPause()` will be called when the activity no longer is in the foreground from an input standpoint
- `onStop()` will be called when the activity no longer is in the foreground from a visibility standpoint

Comment: thx for answer. is there anyway to hide this activity? for example run some thread with this one activity and back to previous activity on second thread?

Comment: i need this for googleMap instance hendled on actvity, because i want to get GPS position all the time

Comment: @user2420602: Getting the GPS position has nothing to do with maps. Maps V1 is deprecated, and Maps V2 deprecated the ways to get the location from Maps V2. Use `LocationManager` and/or `LocationClient` to access the device's location. Beyond that, there is no way to hide an activity in a way that would somehow avoid `onPause()` and `onStop()`.